# How to concatenate two table to on table with dropdown?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to concatenate this two table to one tabel. year and month, in dropdown. Is it like

```
year-month
0-1
1-2
1-3
```

Is it possible to do it in mysql query.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  CONCAT( a.year, '-', b.month ) AS year_month
FROM
  year_table a,
  month_table b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
select concat(a.yearNo,'-',b.monthNo) as yearMonth from table1 a, table2 b where a.someID=b.someID
```

Comment: I think he meant from two different tables.

Comment: @DainisAbols Yerk, watching the olympics heh, my home country and country I live in are playing at the moment. Attention == Null :) +1 to your answer anyhow.